# waiting time not waiting properly(the right amount of ticks)

Tags: netlogo

This is a simulation I'm trying to run but I seem to have a problem with the waiting time (ticks).

I can't make my turtles(Shoppers) wait for the right amount of ticks, and I have found that the amount of turtles directly influences the amount of waiting time ticks.

waiting time is an attribute that tells the shoppers to stay put before they start walking towards their next destination.

```
extensions[gis]
breed [shopper  shoppers]
breed [places place]
breed [cityts cityt]

shopper-own [person x y cid route shopper_type destination last-destination waiting_time step starting_point cityx cityy]

turtles-own [std wflag ]

places-own [shopper_type ycoor xcoor locality ]

cityts-own[shopper_type org xc yc]

patches-own[netlogo]

globals [ speed  last_place]





to setup

   setup_world
   setup_color
   ask cityts [set hidden? true]
   reset-ticks

end





to go
  ask shopper  with [shopper_type   != "rtqq"] [walk-towards]
; ask shopper  with [shopper_type = "lvl2" and shopper_type ="lvl2" ] [omw]
  if ticks >= 1440 [stop]
  tick
end



to loc
  ask cityts [
  output-show ticks
  output-show xcor
  output-show ycor
  output-show label
  output-show who
  ]
end



to output-locations
  output-show self
  output-show xcor
  output-show ycor
end




to walk-towards
  ask shopper [
  if shopper_type  != "aaa" [
    rep

  ifelse waiting_time > 0 [
  set waiting_time waiting_time - 1
  set step step + 1]
  [omw]] ]
end

to omw
  if destination = false [fd 1]
 ifelse distance destination > 0.1
      [face destination
      forward speed]
      [move-to destination
      next_place
      set step 0]
end


to set_destination [NUM]
  set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = NUM]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself]
end

to wt [NUM]
  set waiting_time NUM + random 10 - random 10
  set waiting_time waiting_time - 1
end


to setup_world

  create-places 3
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 345
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 789
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 3344
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 3232
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 1937
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 951
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 987
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 234
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 912
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 567
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 8529
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 891
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 1927
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 1826
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 1725
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 456
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 1013
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 7891
  ]
    create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 3322
  ]
      create-places 3
  [

    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set label 678
  ]


  create-shopper  3 [
      set size 1
      set waiting_time 0
      set shopper_type  "lvl1"
      set cid 1
      set shape "person"
      set starting_point one-of (turtles with [label = 1725])
;      set xcor random-float  25
;      set ycor random-float  25
;      set ctiyx xcor of starting_point
;      set cityy ycor of starting_point
      set speed  0.1
      set route random 6  ]
  ask shopper [
    set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789 ]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself]
    set last-destination "boop" ]



; create-shopper  2 [
;      set size 1
;      set waiting_time 0
;      set shopper_type  "lvl2"
;      set cid 7
;      set shape "person"
;      set xcor random-float  25
;      set ycor random-float  25
;      set speed 0.1
;      set route random 5  ]
;  ask shopper [
;    set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789 ]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself]
;    set last-destination "boop" ]
;
;


; create-ambolansces 1 [
;      set size 1
;      set waiting_time 0
;      set shopper_type  "lvl3"
;      set shape "car"
;      set xcor random-float  25
;      set ycor random-float  25
;        set speed 0.1
;        set route random 3 ]
;  ask shopper [
;  set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789 ]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself]
;    set last-destination "boop"]




end




to next_place

if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
   if route = 0 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "345"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "789" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3344]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "3344" ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "3344" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3232]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards set last-destination "3232" ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "3232" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1937]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1937"  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1937" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 951]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 80 walk-towards rep set last-destination "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
  if route = 1 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 100 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 5 walk-towards rep set last-destination "234"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 951]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
  if route = 2 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "912"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 567]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards  set last-destination "567" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "567" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
  if route = 3 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "987"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "789" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 567]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "678" ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "678" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards set last-destination "891" ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1927]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1927"  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1927" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 80 walk-towards rep set last-destination "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
  if route = 4 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1937]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 100 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "1937" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "1937" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1826]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1826" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "1826" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1725]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1725"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "1725" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 5 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3322]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  = "lvl1"[
  if route = 5 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "912"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]





if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
   if route = 0 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "345"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "789" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3344]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "3344" ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "3344" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3232]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards  set last-destination "3232" ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "3232" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1937]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1937"  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1937" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 951]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 80 walk-towards rep set last-destination "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
  if route = 1 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 100 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 5 walk-towards rep set last-destination "234"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 951]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
  if route = 2 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "912"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 567]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards  set last-destination "567" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "567" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
  if route = 3 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "987"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "789" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 678]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards   set last-destination "678" ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "678" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards set last-destination "891" ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1927]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1927"  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1927" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 80 walk-towards rep set last-destination "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
  if route = 4 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1937]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 100 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "1937" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "1937" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1826]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 10 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1826" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "1826" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1725]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1725"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "1725" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 5 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 3322]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 40 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type  =  "lvl2"[
  if route = 5 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 60 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "912"  ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 345]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 30 walk-towards rep set last-destination "345"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "345" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 70 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 8529]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 50 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 6 ]]]]]]]]









if  shopper_type  = "lvl3"[
   if route = 0 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "987"]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "987"  [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "789"  ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789"[set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "456"  ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "912"rep ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1013]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "1013"rep  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1013" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "boop" set route random 3 rep ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  = "lvl3"[
  if route = 1 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "234"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 3 ]]]]]]]]
if  shopper_type  = "lvl3"[
  if route = 2 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "234"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards rep set last-destination  "boop" set route random 3 ]]]]]]]]



if  shopper_type = "lvl4"[
   if route = 0 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination  "987"]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "987"  [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "789"  ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "789"[set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "456"  ]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 912]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "912" ]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "912" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 1013]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "1013"  ]
                    [if last-destination = "1013" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "boop" set route random 3  ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type = "lvl4"[
  if route = 1 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "234"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination  "boop" set route random 3 ]]]]]]]]

if  shopper_type = "lvl4"[
  if route = 2 [
            ifelse last-destination ="boop" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination  "789" ]
            [ ifelse last-destination = "789" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 456]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "456" ]
              [ ifelse last-destination = "456" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 234]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "234"]
                [ ifelse last-destination = "234" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 987]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "987"]
                  [ifelse last-destination = "987" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination "7891" ]
                    [if last-destination = "7891" [set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 891]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] wt 20 walk-towards  set last-destination  "boop" set route random 3 ]]]]]]]]







END





to setup_color
  ask shopper  with [shopper_type  = "lvl1"] [set color cyan]
  ask shopper  with [shopper_type  = "lvl2"] [set color pink]
end





TO rep
  output-show ticks
  output-show xcor
  output-show ycor
  output-show last-destination
  output-show cid
end
```

*this is an edited excerpt of my code I made because the original is using GIS  layers for coordinates and turtle making

Comment: To improve your chances of getting a useful answer, you may want to edit down your code to a minimal example showing the problem behavior, going so far as to making a toy model from scratch if you need to (see the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Without delving into your code, it does look like you're asking shoppers multiple times per tick. For example, in `to go` you `ask shopper` to `walk-towards`, which contains another `ask shopper`, which means each shopper will ask each other shopper to do a thing.

Comment: thank you, for the comment it seems to be the problem. ill check it with the original code. i went a bit to far with the model i just wanted to recreate the same conditions as the original project so if my mistake lie somewhere else someone could point it out.